# AWS management console - Language

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, devops

Under a AWS main account we have lot of users from Japan and India. We need the console to be in English for offshore (India) and in Japanese for Onsite without any changes in the access part . How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

Have your users switch the language themselves in the bottom left corner of the console.

[image]

Comment: If the users change the language settings , its reflecting for the Japan folks too. That is the problem.

Comment: This is on a per-user basis - are you using the same IAM user for all of your users? In that case you have a whole different problem.